# Creating a document in another collection with some fields from a document in different collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document in collection A as below:

```
{
  [{
     "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
     "prcCode" : 1,
     "communication" : [
       {
            "communicationCode" : 1,
            "communicationDesc" : "SMS"
       },
       {
            "communicationCode" : 2,
            "communicationDesc" : "Email"
       }
     ]
   }]
}
```

I need to create document in collection B as below using the above document:

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("234"),
   "prcCode" : 1,
   "communicationCode" : 1,
   "communicationDesc" : "SMS"
}


{
   "_id":ObjectId("335"),
   "prcCode" : 1,
   "communicationCode" : 2,
   "communicationDesc" : "Email"
}
```

can any one help me in creating as am unable to figure out.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [$out](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) which takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a specified collection. check following query :

```
db.collectionA.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$communication"
}, {
  "$project": {
    "prcCode": 1,
    "communicationCode": "$communication.communicationCode",
    "communicationDesc": "$communication.communicationDesc",
    "_id": 0
  }
}, {
  "$out": "collectionB"
})
```

Comment: thank you for the response.but  am looking for node.js code